# How to calculate the term structure of an index that doesn’t have futures

Tags: futures, forecasting, vix, term-structure

I would like to calculate the term structure of the VVIX index.

Only way I have found so far is forecasting historical prices N months out.

Any other idea?

Comment: Cboe calculates VVIX term structure values for all VIX option expirations.

Comment: From CBOE web site:  "Does Cboe calculate a term structure of the VVIX? Cboe calculates VVIX term structure values for all VIX option expirations. The VVIX term structure value associated with a specific expiration, e.g. April 2012, measures the expected volatility of the price of April 2012 VIX futures. The term structure of VVIX is usually downward sloping. How often is [it] published? The Cboe publishes the VVIX every 15 seconds and its term structure daily at the close" https://www.cboe.com/us/indices/dashboard/vvix/

Comment: In summary: at S&P option dates you can calculate points on the S&P vol term structure and at VIX option dates you can calculate data points of the VVIX term structure, using the respective option prices.